# SQL: Change result of SELECT based on boolean value

Tags: sql, string

Let's assume I have the following table (PostgreSQL):

```
name(string) |value(boolean)
----------------------------
Dan          |false
Bob          |true
Anne         |false
Larry        |true
```

Now I want to retrieve all the names:

```
SELECT name as myName, value as myValue FROM table
```

**but** whenever "value" is "true", I want to append "cat" to the name.
So the result for "name" from my query should be: "Dan" "Bobcat" "Anne" "Larrycat".

Is this possible?

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Comment: Column value's data type? (Poor column name...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`explain` all proposed queries to find the most efficient

```
SELECT CONCAT(name, 'cat') AS name, value FROM t WHERE value = 'true'
UNION ALL
SELECT name, value FROM t WHERE value = 'false'
```

Comment: UNION ALL would be more efficient.

Comment: @jarlh agree, changing

Comment: This fits my purpose the best, thanks to everyone who answered!

Answer (score 4):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN value = 'true' THEN CONCAT(name, 'cat') ELSE name END AS name,
    value
FROM yourTable;
```

I am assuming your are using MySQL, which uses the `CONCAT` function to do string concatenation.

Answer (score 2):

You would use a `case` expression:

```
select (case when value = 'true' then name || 'cat' else name end) as name,
       value
from t;
```